# Can i develop medical software for Cell Phone?

Tags: mobile-phones, mobile-website

I am programmer of ASP .NET using C#, recently working on .Net Framework 3.5

I am wondering for medical softwares for cell phone. As I visited list of softwares for medical science:
http://cellsindex.com/mobile-softwares-for-Medical-c11

Can anybody help me how can i start development in cell phone applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonoTouch http://monotouch.net/ is a good option to create iPhone Apps using .Net

Comment: it is commercial application. is there any other open source alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already experienced in ,net you can try out [Windows mobile development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

based on cell phone OS you have to use different SDK (like Windows OS 6.5 - 6.0 - 5.0 - android - symbian - java or etc)